# Gwt @NotNull default message override for foreign language

Tags: java, validation, gwt

When I annotate my FIELDS with @NotNull and validate the bean, I get the following default messages for these locales

en_CA

```
May not be null
```

fr_CA

```
ne peut pas être nul
```

I would like to change the fr_CA message to `ne peut pas être vide`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to find and replace this message in `ValidationMessages_fr_CA.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class UserBean {
@Size(min=13, message="{creditcard.length}")
public String getCreditCard() {
    return this.creditCard;
}
```

}

and creditcard.length=credit card length must be at least 13 characters has to be in the ValidationMessages.properties ValidationMessages_fr.properties